# Emberjs and jquery restrict textbox values

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have created a textbox which should contain only integers or decimal. Its working fine normally but whem i am linking with emberjs its not working

Here is my jquery

```
$(function () { alert('test')//This alert is working
        $("input[name='sum']").keydown(function (event) {


            if (event.shiftKey == true) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }

            if ((event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57) || (event.keyCode >= 96 && event.keyCode <= 105) || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 39 || event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 190) {

            } else {
                event.preventDefault();
            }

            if($(this).val().indexOf('.') !== -1 && event.keyCode == 190)
                event.preventDefault();

        });
    });
```

Here is my ember handlebar

```
{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="sum_up" name="sum"}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize Ember.TextField to do this. Ember View supports native browser events..[Refer this](http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/the-view-layer/)

```
App.TestView = Ember.TextField.extend({
keyDown : function (event) {
   //Do your stuffs here
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WBKzk/1/)

Hope it helps ..

Comment: [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/WBKzk/2/) If i have two textbox both not working only one textbox should have this restriction.